# Any way to strip namespace garbage from XML file?

Tags: xpath, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I need to select some nodes from an XML file (AppNamespace.xaml from a Silverlight XAP file, not that it matters), but the file has namespace stuff so XPath doesn't work. I could waste most of a day trial-and-erroring the bondage-and-discipline nightmare of XmlNamespaceManager and end up with hopelessly fragile code that can't tolerate the slightest variation in the input file (not a great idea in production code), or I could use the ludicrous local-name() syntax[1].

But it would be more convenient to use XPath as a human-readable query language that can be used to return specified nodes or attribute values from arbitrary XML files.

So is there any way to strip the line-noise out of the file? Or am I stuck? Is the labyrinthine imbecility of Linq-to-XML truly the lesser evil?

[1]

```
//*[local-name() = 'Deployment']/*[local-name() = 'Deployment.Parts']/*[local-name() = 'AssemblyPart']/@*[local-name()='Name']
```

## Update

Five years down the road, I stand behind the term "labyrinthine imbecility" with every fiber of my being, except for a few fibers that want to use something much stronger.

Comment: Seeing that this is a XAML file, the namespaces used will be standardized, so I don't share your view that this would be unnecessarily brittle. Also, XML namespaces have a very real reason for their existance - don't just label them as "garbage" - learn to use them to your advantage!

Comment: @marc_s, I completely agree with Mr Plunkett on this one. Code that is difficult to write tends to be brittle. Code stability is of paramount importance, and ignoring the nagging feeling that something will be brittle is foolish. That is not to say that what you say has no merit, but saying "suck it up" is worse.

Comment: @Star: except he didn't say "suck it up" (i.e. yes it's bad but ignore that and do it anyway). He said there is a reason for  XML namespaces, and you can learn to use them to your advantage. I have done so, and namespaces are not that bad; the most inconvenient part is learning how each XPath-to-my-code interface handles them. And XmlNamespaceManager is not that bad either... it's fairly logical. Mixing XML vocabularies *without* namespaces is brittle.

Comment: @Ed, what environment are you developing in, so we can know what methods are available/practical? You mentioned linq-to-xml, but it sounds like you're looking for alternatives to it. I guess you're using .NET?

Comment: LarsH, you correctly inferred .NET.

Comment: marc_s, one of the strong points of XML IMHO is "duck typing" -- if they change some part of the schema that doesn't affect me, I see no reason for my code to break over it. Breaking changes should break stuff, certainly, but this kills not just any backwards compatibility, but any hope of it. Do I misunderstand pretty badly, or is any change to the schema simply going to break any attempt to parse the file at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ed, [here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356942.aspx) of using namespaces with the System.Xml.XPath Extensions class. I've modified it to match the input you're looking at:

```
string markup = @"
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" ...>
  <Deployment.Parts>
    <AssemblyPart x:Name="xamlName" Source="assembly" />
  </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
";

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(markup));
XElement root = XElement.Load(reader);

XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
nsm.AddNamespace("dep", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment");

IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
   root.XPathSelectElements("//dep:Deployment/dep:Deployment.Parts/dep:AssemblyPart/@x:Name", nsm);
foreach (XElement el in elements)
    Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Not very complicated. Obviously you already know about XmlNamespaceManager, but I think you got a worse impression of it than it deserves.

When you say "hopelessly fragile code that can't tolerate the slightest variation in the input file", are you blaming namespaces in general, or XmlNamespaceManager? I don't see how either one makes it fragile... any more so than XML processing code *without* namespaces will not tolerate certain changes in the input document, but will tolerate others.

Have a little respect for other intelligent people in the industry, take a little time to understand the advantages behind a design before you dismiss it, and you will usually find that there are good reasons for what was done.

Not that XML namespaces couldn't be improved upon. However nobody has managed to produce a better standard and get it accepted by the community.

Comment: Lars, thanks again. My hope was to be able to traverse XML in a given form without having to know in advance what the namespaces are going to be. If an attribute is called "x:Name", I don't mind calling it that, but it's annoying to have to know what schema URL "x" refers to. Frankly, I don't necessarily care. It's valuable for code to be able to very strictly validate its own XML, and the namespace stuff allows that -- but it's also valuable for code to be able to fairly casually look at somebody else's XML.

Comment: @Ed, thanks for your comment. I agree, it would be a hassle to have to be aware of the schemas involved, just in order to select bits from an XML document. But thankfully, there is not a necessary linkage from namespaces to schemas (or from ns URIs to anything else... they're just abstract identifiers). You are free to ignore the schema and ignore validation completely, and that will not interfere with your ability to select parts of the document using XPath (unless you start getting into schema-aware processing with data types or something, but that's rarely required in my experience).

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0 you can use namespace wildcards (if you know what you are doing):

```
//*:Deployment/*:Deployment.Parts/*:AssemblyPart/@Name
```

btw. If an attribute doesn't have a prefix it is in no namespace at all. As this is most often the case, I guess, you don't need `local-name()` for the attribute.

Comment: +1, good suggestion. Does Linq-to-XML support XPath 2.0, do you know?

Comment: @LarsH: There is no XPath 2.0 support in .NET.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll give that a whirl (though I see another comment suggests .NET doesn't do XPath 2.0, darn it...). I did know about unprefixed/namespaceless attributes; been using those for years.

Answer (score 0):

I came here as a result of this search: [image]

and I am adding an "Answer" to cheer on your "5 years on" update.

I was motivated to do this because I have an XML document that uses a tonne of namespaces -

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:x2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel2" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
```

and APPARENTLY I have to know what all those namespaces are in advance in order to hard code the XmlNamespaceManager, or write some code that parses the namespace declarations and adds the relevant name spaces myself. Why in the name of all that is holy does the XmlDocument not manage to do that all by itself?

```
XmlDocument databaseXml = new XmlDocument();
databaseXml.LoadXml(xslt.XslTransform);
var dbnsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(databaseXml.NameTable);
dbnsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
dbnsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
XmlElement databaseStylesElement = (XmlElement)database
Xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template");
```